# Can Conda Install Any (Even Older) Version of Python?

Tags: python, conda

I installed conda via https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh and I wanted to install python 3.5 and python 3.6 by

`conda create -n py35_10 python=3.5.5`

However, I get

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.5.5
```

This touches a fundamental question I have about Conda. Does conda support all version of python? When new version of conda comes out, does it drop support to older version of python? If so, does it mean the only way to keep using those python version is by installing older version of conda?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install many versions of Python, including 3.5.5. Use the `conda-forge` channel for this.

```
conda create -n py35_10 -c conda-forge python=3.5.5
```

See https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/files, and view the dropdown of available versions. Even 1.x and 2.x versions of Python are available.

Though it seems that the Anaconda channel also has Python 3.5.5 https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=3.5.5.

Comment: Note that older Python versions from the **defaults** / **anaconda** channel may require enabling the **free** channel. An immediate way to access this is including `-c free`, however, there is also a configuration setting (`restore_free_channel`) to include this by default (see [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/free-channel.html)).